# css - can't get dropdown nav to show above content below it

Tags: html, css

I'm making a CSS dropdown navigation and I can't get the dropdown to show up above the content in the div below the navigation div. How do I do this, without positioning both divs absolutely and specifying a z-index? You can see my example here:

http://stage.fourwallsla.com/in-the-neighborhood

Comment: Why don't you want to specify z-index on #nav_container div?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have already used absolute positioning I see, but anyways why not add z-index to it?

```
#container #top_nav .subnav {
    position: absolute;
    top: 37px;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 1000;
}
```

That fixes it, you just need to work on a better background color for it now!

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it without z-index specifing or swapping blocks in your markup

Add to your css

```
#container #nav_container {
    z-index: 2;
}
#container #nav_container li a {
    background-color: #fff;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Giving the "feature" div a negative z-index would also work (tested in Chrome Firebug)

```
z-index:-1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#container #top_nav .subnav{
  z-index: 2;
}

#container #top_nav .subnav li > a{
  background: #fff;
}
```

Comment: Did my answer differ a lot from yours?

Comment: Yes it does - you added background color to '#container #nav_container li a' but the change should be made in this class '#container #top_nav .subnav li > a'

Comment: adding `background-color` is not solution of @mheavers's problem but only small changes on my own initiative

Comment: @Vladimir Starkov What...........? plus the class names you mentioned are not available in the link mheavers has shared